# Lightbox loading gif not showing immediately upon clicking on link

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox

I have a search box. When the user clicks the search icon it fires an ajax form that then displays the results inside of the lightbox.

The problem lies in the fact that the loading gif isn't showing until like the last possible second. The query takes a few seconds so I need this gif to show during this time.

How do I get the loading gif to show the second the search icon is clicked which just points to the script below?

```
<script>
    $('#performSearch').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("Search", "RespondentSearch"))",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { query: $('#query').val() },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#search_results").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="sidebarSearch">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="respondent search..." id="query" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" />
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
    <a href="#search_results" rel="lightbox" id="performSearch"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tag  to represent the loading gif, which will initially be hidden. In the javascript click event to show the loading you use the function show () and when the ajax return the result of the request you use the function hide () to hide the loading.

You can see some loading this link http://www.ajaxload.info/

Here's how to change the code:

```
<pre>
    <script>
        $('#performSearch').on('click', function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("Search", "RespondentSearch"))",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { query: $('#query').val() },
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#search_results").html(result);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="sidebarSearch">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="respondent search..." id="query" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" />
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <a href="#search_results" rel="lightbox" id="performSearch"></a>
        <img src="caminho/loading.gif" id="loading" style="display: none;"/>
    </div>
</pre>
```

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Sorry, I put this tag only publish the answers, you can delete and leave the rest of the code.